# chalkboardy stuff cute but a little distracting

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, user-interface, se2.0

The "chalkboardy" up/down arrows, star, etc. are kinda weird... any chance you could just use plain up/down arrows like on most other stackexchange sites?

Comment: I understand this is just for the beta.

Comment: See the [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq); "Why does this site look so “sketchy”?"

Comment: This is definitely by design. [Jin Yang](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) is a great designer, and the chalkboard theme is no exception.

Answer (score 5):

From the [FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/faq):

#### Why does this site look so “sketchy”?

The site is still in the process of being defined and constructed, so a temporary placeholder design will be used until the site is fully formed and ready to leave beta. Once the site is no longer beta it will have a logo, domain, and design of the community's choice -- see our [meta-discussion site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you have ideas or feedback!